# How can I find out which places are most often frequented in a given area, preferably with a way to categorize places (e.g., restaurant or market)?

Tags: online-resources, thailand

How can I find out which places are most often frequented in a given area, preferably with a way to categorize places (e.g., restaurant or market)? If country-specific, I'm looking for Thailand.

[I first thought of looking at which location has the most reviews/ratings in a given area on Google Maps](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158268/1810), [but I'm told that using review counts on Google Maps a good approximation for the popularity of a location](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158306/1810). What other solutions exist?

---

The motivations as a traveler to find out which places are most often frequented are well stated in https://www.top-rated.online/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200714024058/https://www.top-rated.online/)):

> When you travel to a new city, it takes time till you find your new
> favorite place or visit what's best here. You will want to visit the
> best places there are, but it is so difficult to find them!
>
> The most reviewed and top rated places are ones that you can trust.
> But take everything with a grain of salt.
>
> There are also many hidden gems that are extremely good, but are not
> that popular. Also, always keep an eye on worst reviewed places and
> tourist traps that you should avoid.

Answer (score 6):

TripAdvisor usually has a good overview of city's highlights, in the form of `< City >'s top attractions'. It's not perfect, but much more tailored to travellers than google maps, and also curated.

It also has rudimentary categorization.