# How can I find a big pharmacy in Istanbul?

Tags: health, turkey, istanbul

I'm currently staying in Istanbul and need to buy an over-the-counter medicine that is a little rare. I went around a few pharmacies around my hotel, but they're all relatively small and don't carry the product that I need. How can I locate a list of big pharmacies that would likely have a lot of choice? Is there a particular keyword that distinguishes small pharmacies from big ones?

Comment: Ask the small pharmacies who would stock the drug you need. I'd expect that they would be able to tell you.

Comment: If you're in a hotel/hostel the reception should know where the nearest large pharmacy is. Failing that, the tourist information office may also know

Comment: Aside: the definitions of 'over-the-counter' and 'prescription' medicines varies by country, and some may be dispensed by a pharmacist after an assessment. Please see [Over-the-counter drug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-counter_drug).

Comment: [How can I find out which places are most often frequented in a given area, preferably with a way to categorize places (e.g., restaurant or market)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/158309/1810)

Comment: @Arthur'sPass tried the pharmacy itself, they said they're not sure. In Europe or the US the pharmacist would offer to backorder any drug if they don't have it available, but I wasn't offered that in Istanbul.

Comment: @CSM tried that, but I think I failed to explain myself properly as I was just sent to the regular small pharmacies that I've already seen around.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt fair point, but in my case its just a food supplement (psyllium), which doesn't actually contain any medicine.

Comment: @JonathanReez psyllium appears to be a food supplement. Have you tried a health-food shop as wekk?

Comment: Perhaps you will get a better answer if you tell us exactly what you are looking for. In the question you are asking about medicine and in a comment, you reveal that it is a food supplement. I am not even sure if I would categorize psyllium as a food supplement, but as a more or less regular food used for baking or cooking. In Germany, you can find psyllium  in most grocery stores and also here, pharmacies would probably find it odd if you try to buy it there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the end I was able to find what I'm looking for by traveling to a pharmacy in one of the big shopping malls (Emaar Square Mall), which had a section with food supplements that I was looking for. I guess the answer is thus to travel to the nearest large shopping mall instead of trying local pharmacies in downtown Istanbul.

Answer (score 2):

Cover the counter pharmaceuticals are also sold online in Turkey and a lot of pharmacies list their inventories there, hence uncommon stuff also appears. Then one can either contact the stores individually or just order online. Few potential webpages to look,

https://www.n11.com

https://www.gittigidiyor.com/

https://www.amazon.com.tr/

https://www.hepsiburada.com/